# Como selecionar apenas a maior movimentação no Sql?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para buscar a ultima movimentação no estoque de cada produto. Acontece que na clausula que eu fiz, ele está me retornando todas as vendas referente aquele produto, sendo que eu preciso apenas da ultima... As vendas são ordenadas por id. Eu elaborei o seguinte código:

```
SELECT estoque.id, produto.gtin, produto.descricao, estoque.saldo_atual, estoque.loja 
FROM produto 
INNER JOIN estoque ON (produto.id = estoque.id_produto_empresa)
WHERE estoque.loja = '16'                       
ORDER BY produto.descricao ASC
```

Esta Query está me retornando todas as movimentações de cada item, porém eu necessito que para cada gtin, seja exibido o maior ID.

**Exemplo:**

`id 766 gtin 004778 descricao AGITADOR BWC06A/BWG10A/WL09A/CWE06A/B/CWL08C-NF`

`id 2721 gtin 000672 descricao ALCOOL METILICO 500ML`

[image: Print Retorno do banco]
Agradeço muito quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Resolvido... Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supondo que a identificação do produto, é só o gtin, você pode usar `rank` com `Partition`:

```
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY produto.gtin ORDER BY estoque.id desc)
```

> ps. Ordenar pelo número da venda, vai ter problemas com isso.

**F**aça o select rankeando as "vendas", de forma descendente. Ou seja, a última venda (estoque.id é a venda certo?) será 0.
Então você seleciona dessa tabela, todos os registros em que o rank for 0.

**Exemplo:**

```
With tabela as (
SELECT 
    estoque.id, 
    produto.gtin, 
    produto.descricao, 
    estoque.saldo_atual, 
    estoque.loja, 
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY produto.gtin ORDER BY estoque.id desc) as i
FROM produto 
INNER JOIN estoque ON (produto.id = estoque.id_produto_empresa)
WHERE estoque.loja = '16')

select * from tabela where i = 0;
```

> ps. Tá bem corrido aqui, se puder testar e dar um feedback. Se puder fazer o SQLFiddle também ajuda.

Comment: Eu consegui aqui e postei a solução no SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/76aabc/5)

Comment: Eu não conhecia esta função RANK, vou dar uma estudada nela, muito obrigado pelo esforço em me ajudar, de verdade mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Teste dessa forma:

```
SELECT produto.gtin, produto.descricao, 
  (SELECT max(estoque.id) 
    FROM estoque 
    WHERE estoque.id_produto_empresa = produto.id) AS estoque_id, 
  estoque.saldo_atual, estoque.loja 
FROM produto 
INNER JOIN estoque ON (produto.id = estoque.id_produto_empresa) 
WHERE estoque.loja = '16'
GROUP BY produto.descricao
ORDER BY produto.descricao ASC
```

Se possível, coloque sua estrutura no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: ele quer a ultima movimentação de estoque, ou seja, o estoque atual. Sua query irá retornar o maior valor que já teve em estoque

Comment: Eita, entendi a maior movimentação ! Editado. Desculpas !

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo empenho, aqui eu segui a logica do max e solucionei assim:
SELECT 
estoque.id, produto.gtin, produto.descricao, estoque.saldo_atual
FROM
produto INNER JOIN 
estoque ON (produto.id = estoque.id_produto_empresa)
Where estoque.id=(select max(id) from estoque e where e.id_produto_empresa=produto.id ) 
GROUP BY estoque.id, produto.gtin, produto.descricao, estoque.saldo_atual
ORDER BY produto.descricao ASC

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, me salvou aqui na empresa.

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma subquery que retorna todos os IDs de estoque desejados utilizando `max()`, agrupando pelo que eles têm em comum, que pelo que entendi a partir de sua pergunta é o `id_produto`. Você pode até já filtrar a loja para gerar um recordset menor e agilizar a query lá na frente. Como por exemplo:

```
select * from estoque 
where id in (select max(id) from estoque where loja = 16 group by id_produto);
```

Ou, evitando o uso de `in` e fazendo `join` para melhor performance:

```
select * from estoque e1 join
  (select max(id) as id from estoque where loja = 16 group by id_produto) e2 
  on e1.id = e2.id
```

Isso te resultaria em um id de estoque (o maior, ou mais recente) para cada produto naquela loja:

```
| id | id_produto | loja |
|----|------------|------|
|  4 |          2 |   16 |
|  5 |          3 |   16 |
|  8 |          1 |   16 |
|  9 |          4 |   16 |
```

Por fim, é só grudar esse estoque filtrado na sua query que faz `join` com a tabela de produtos para pegar descrições, etc. Eu sugiro o uso de [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) com `with`, que torna a coisa toda bem mais legível:

```
with e as (
  select e1.id, e1.id_produto, e1.loja from estoque e1 join
    (select max(id) as id from estoque 
     where loja = 16 group by id_produto) e2
    on e1.id = e2.id
)
select
  e.id,
  p.gtin, 
  p.descricao,
  e.loja
from produto p join e on p.id = e.id_produto;
```

Isso te retornaria algo como:

```
| id | gtin | descricao | loja |
|----|------|-----------|------|
|  8 | 0001 | Produto a |   16 |
|  4 | 0002 | Produto b |   16 |
|  5 | 0003 | Produto c |   16 |
|  9 | 0004 | Produto d |   16 |
```

Segue exemplo no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c67dd/4

Nesse fiddle você pode ver que montei um schema simplificado, mas baseado no que você apresentou pela sua pergunta. Se houver algo que não caiba no seu schema, sugiro que poste um fiddle com amostra dos dados para que possamos efetuar testes mais fidedignos.

Comment: Eu agradeço de coração. Isto me ajudou muito a encontrar o caminho. Eu postei aqui a solução baseada no que você me informou e deu tudo certo, fico muito agradecido.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/76aabc/5